# When trying to build the game I'm getting error/s in the editor console but not in the visual studio. How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Errors in editor]

In the script I'm using SceneManagement :

```
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
```

But it's in gray like I'm not using it in the script. But if I will remove the line :

```
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
```

It will not show errors in the visual studio but if I will try to compile now the game in the editor it will show 10 errors in the console of places need the SceneManagement.

Never had errors before in this script. It started once I tried to build the game.

Screenshot of part of my script. SceneManagement is in gray like not needed or in use but it is :

[image: Part of script]

And the building settings window in the editor :

[image: Build Settings]

I tried to shut down exit the visual studio and re opened it from the editor double click on a script but it didn't change anything.

The complete script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

public class ObjectsReplace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabToInit;
    public bool deleteAllShaders = false;

    private const string c_doorRight = "Door_Right";
    private const string c_doorLeft = "Door_Left";
    private const string c_doorShieldFxLocked = "DoorShieldFXLocked";

    public List<GameObject> FindDoors(string[] SpecificParents)
    {
        GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        if (deleteAllShaders == false)
        {
            List<GameObject> toRemove = new List<GameObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < allDoors.Count; i++)
            {
                bool match = true;
                for (int x = 0; x < SpecificParents.Length; x++)
                {
                    match &= allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != SpecificParents[x];
                }
                if (match)
                {
                    toRemove.Add(allDoors[i]);
                }
            }
            foreach (var it in toRemove)
            {
                allDoors.Remove(it);
            }
        }

        return allDoors;
    }

    public void DeleteAllShaders()
    {
        if(deleteAllShaders == true)
        {
            UpdateOrAddShaderPrefabToDoors();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateOrAddShaderPrefabToDoors()
    {
        var allDoors = FindDoors(new string[]{ "Wall_Door_Long_01", "Wall_Door_Long_02", "Wall_Interior_Door_02" });

        HashSet<GameObject> prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove = new HashSet<GameObject>();
        allDoors.ForEach(doorGameObject =>
        {
            List<GameObject> shadersChildren = new List<GameObject>();
            for (int i=0; i<doorGameObject.transform.childCount ;i++)
            {
                if (doorGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).name.StartsWith(c_doorShieldFxLocked))
                {
                    shadersChildren.Add(doorGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
                }
            }
            foreach (GameObject shader in shadersChildren)
            {
                GameObject outermostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(shader);
                prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove.Add(outermostPrefabInstanceRoot);
            }
        });

        foreach (GameObject parent in prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove)
        {
            Modify(parent, RemoveFunc);
        }

        HashSet<GameObject> prefabParentsOfDoors = new HashSet<GameObject>();
        allDoors.ForEach(doorGameObject =>
        {
            GameObject outermostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(doorGameObject);
            prefabParentsOfDoors.Add(outermostPrefabInstanceRoot);
        });

        if (deleteAllShaders == false)
        {
            foreach (GameObject parent in prefabParentsOfDoors)
            {
                AddShaderToPrefab(parent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddShaderToPrefab(GameObject child)
    {
        Modify(child, AddShaderToAllDoorsFunc);
    }

    private GameObject AddShaderToAllDoorsFunc(GameObject prefab)
    {
        var children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        //Debug.Log($"Total child count before:{children.Count()}");
        int doorsFound = 0;
        foreach (Transform trans in children)
        {
            if (trans.name == c_doorLeft || (trans.name == c_doorRight))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Found door, adding");
                GameObject shader = GetDoorShaderPrefab();

                // clone prefab and attach to parent
                Instantiate(shader, trans); 
                doorsFound++;
            }
        }

        children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        //Debug.Log($"Total child count after:{children.Count()}, doors found:{doorsFound}");

        return prefab;
    }

    private GameObject GetDoorShaderPrefab()
    {
        string[] shieldPrefab = AssetDatabase.FindAssets(c_doorShieldFxLocked);
        //Debug.Assert(shieldPrefab.Length == 1, "Expected exactly 1 shield like this...");
        string shieldGuid = shieldPrefab[0];
        string prefabPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(shieldGuid);
        GameObject prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
        //Debug.Assert(prefab != null, "Expected prefab to load");
        return prefab;
    }

    private GameObject RemoveFunc(GameObject prefab)
    {
        var children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        //Debug.Log($"child count:{children.Count()}");
        foreach (Transform trans in children)
        {
            if (trans.name.StartsWith(c_doorShieldFxLocked))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Found door shader");
                DestroyImmediate(trans.gameObject);
            }
        }

        children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        //Debug.Log($"child count:{children.Count()}");

        return prefab;
    }

    private void Modify(GameObject parentPrefab, Func<GameObject,GameObject> modifyActionOnPrefab)
    {
        // Get the Prefab Asset root GameObject and its asset path.
        string assetPath = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(parentPrefab);

        // Load the contents of the Prefab Asset.
        GameObject prefab = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(assetPath);

        //PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance(mostPrefabInstanceRoot, PrefabUnpackMode.Completely, UnityEditor.InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);

        prefab = modifyActionOnPrefab(prefab);

        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(prefab, assetPath);
        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(prefab);
    }
}
```

This is the editor script I'm using too with the mono script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectsReplace))]
public class ObjectsReplaceEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        ObjectsReplace myScript = (ObjectsReplace)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            myScript.UpdateOrAddShaderPrefabToDoors();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(20);

        if(GUILayout.Button("Delete all shaders"))
        {
            myScript.DeleteAllShaders();
        }
    }
}
```

Again ! what is going on :

1. I can run the game in the editor without any problems. No errors no problems.
2. I can compile and save the scripts in the visual studio without any problem no errors no problems.
3. I can't build the game in the editor only !!! when building the game it's showing the errors in the unity editor console only ! Still no errors in the visual studio. I can play the game in the editor I can't build the game.
4. The namespace SceneManagement exist in the script either using UnityEngine or UnityEditor but this is not the problem. The problem is no matter what I'm using UnityEngine or UnityEditor with SceneManagement the SceneManagement is gray like no in use but it is in use !
5. If I delete remove the scripts the mono and editor both I can build the game !
6. I don't understand yet why in the build settings when building it give me this errors but they are not showing in the visual studio !

Comment: This can happen when you have platform specific defines. What does the rest of ObjectsReplace.cs look like?

Comment: @Iggy I just edited my question added the complete script. But why it's not showing the errors in the visua lstudio and only in the editor ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I'm using now unity version 2019.3.2f1 personal instead 2019.2.5f1 personal ? Maybe it changed something ? I updated my unity few hours ago and it did import for the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UnityEngine.SceneManagement`, not `UnityEditor.SceneManagement`.

Comment: I will but that's not explain why I don't see any error/s in the visual studio and when I build in the visual studio it's all fine not errors. But in the editor when I build the game it's showing errors.

Comment: @DanielLip You can’t use UnityEditor namespace in scripts that you intend to use in the build as the appropriate DLL is not compiled with it. When you need to use the UnityEditor namespace make sure the script is in the Editor folder.

Comment: @Iggy This is not the problem ! The problem is that in the visual studio it's not showing any errors ! In the unity editor I can run my game play it everything is fine. Only when I'm trying to build the game only then it's showing errors in the unity editor only and not in the visual studio.

Comment: And the editor script in in the editor folder and if I'm using UnityEngine.SceneManagement then try to build the game it give me in the editor only only !!!! 10 new errors like other things in the mono script need to use with the UnityEditor.SceneManagement not engine !!! When using UnityEngine it give me 10 errors when using UnityEditor.SceneManagement it give me only 1 error like SceneManagement is not exist but it does in the script only gray like not in use but it is in use !

Comment: And I never had this errors or problems with this two scripts. It started few hours ago.  And why it's showing errors only in the unity editor and only when building the game ? If there are errors why I can play the game in the editor ?

Comment: In special cases we cannot aboid to use the UnityEditor.SceneManagement and it cannot be replaced. But we don't need it in the built veIrsion.

In the posted situation your answer does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you probably found a solution already but to clarify it for others: the problem is the fact that you are using the namespace `UnityEditor`.

`UnityEditor` is only available when running the project inside the editor. You would have to find another way of saving your Prefab. You can save the information you need in `PlayerPrefs` and get rid of the `UnityEditor` namespace. Use `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` instead of `UnityEditor.SceneManagement`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the prepocessor to exclude the editor code from building process:

```
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
      Yourcode(); 
    #endif
```

Hope this helps.